# Transpose both columns and the first row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please help transposing this df. Can't think of better way doing it:

df: Yellow marked are column names

[image]

outcome I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try via `T` attribute,`rename_axis()`,`reset_index()` and `melt()` method:

```
out=(df.T
     .rename_axis(index=['Group','Weeks'])
     .reset_index()
     .melt(['Group','Weeks'],var_name='Days',value_name='Amount'))
```

**OR**

via  `T` attribute,`rename_axis()`,`stack()`,`reset_index()` and `rename()` method:

```
out=(df.T
   .rename_axis(index=['Group','Weeks'])
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .rename(columns={'level_2':'Days',0:'Amount'}))
```

Comment: @PineapplePizza I think you got downvoted because you posted images instead of text so pls remember this in future to provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)